# Is it possible to get the destructured keys of an Object-Parameter while still providing type information to that same Parameter with a generic func?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, object-destructuring

First of all: What do i want to accomplish?

I have an Object containing different dependencys, and various Functions that take this exakt Object as their argument. I dont want to type all these Functions (why is probably not important for this question), so i wrote a Function-Typing-Function. The following is a very simplified example:

```
type dependency_object = {a:number,b:number,c:string};
type dependency_function<T extends keyof dependency_object,R> = (a:{[key in T]: dependency_object[key]})=>R
const give_parameter_types = <T extends dependency_function<keyof dependency_object,any>>(func:T):T => func;
```

It can be used like this:

```
const a_plus_b = give_parameter_types(({a, b}) => a + b);
const c_plus_b= give_parameter_types(({c, b}) => c + b);

const twelfe: number = a_plus_b({a: 5, b: 7,c:'foo'}); // types are only here to clarify the actual returned types
const foo7: string= c_plus_b({a: 5, b: 7,c:'foo'});
```

Ideally, i would like to call these Functions like this

```
const twelfe: number = a_plus_b ({a: 5, b: 7}); // Error: Property 'c' is missing in type
const foo7: string= c_plus_b({b: 7,c:'foo'}); // Error: Property 'a' is missing in type
```

so i tried to extract the keys that where destructured, which lead to this:

```
type unused_keys<BASE_OBJ,FUNC> = {[key in keyof BASE_OBJ]:FUNC extends (a: {[k in Exclude<keyof BASE_OBJ,key>]: BASE_OBJ[k]})=>any ? key  : never}[keyof BASE_OBJ];
type used_keys<BASE_OBJ,FUNC> = Exclude<keyof BASE_OBJ, unused_keys<BASE_OBJ,FUNC>>;
const extract_dependencies = <T>(func:T):dependency_function<used_keys<dependency_object,T>,ReturnType<T>> => func;
const a_plus_b_2: dependency_function<"a" | "b", any> = extract_dependencies(({a, b}) => a + b);
const twelfe: any= a_plus_b({a: 5, b: 7});
```

That works so far, it actually picks up that only a and b are used.
The Problem is that the ReturnType is now any, since the function does not know of the types for a and b. Typescript also tells me that i can't put T into ReturnType, since it does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any', but whenever i add an extends to T other than any or unknown i suddenly loose the Information that only a and b are used.

So here comes the Challenge:
Is it possible to create a single Function combining the Funtionality of extract_dependencies AND give_parameter_types?
Is it possible to get the destructured keys of an Object-Parameter while still providing type information to that same Parameter with a generic func?

The "best" approach i have come up with until now is this one:

```
const combined_through_duplication = <T1,T2 extends dependency_function<keyof dependency_object,any>>(t1:T1,t2:T2): dependency_function<used_keys<dependency_object,T1>,ReturnType<T2>> => t2;
const a_plus_b_3: dependency_function<"a" | "b", number> = combined_through_duplication(
  ({a, b}) => a + b, // a and b are unknown here, but T1 can be used to extract the keys
  ({a, b}) => a + b, // a and b are correctly typed here, so we can take the Returnvalue of T2 for typing
)
const twelfe:number = a_plus_b_3({a:5,b:7});
```

but since this requires me to duplicate the function its hardly of any practical use.

Of course i could just list the "dependencies" in an array together with the function, but i would like to avoid this duplication if possible.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be made possible?
Otherwise an Explanation why changing the T of extract_dependencies to anything else than any or unknown kills my ability to extract the used keys would also be greatly appreciated.

If there is any need for further clarification, please tell me.

Comment: Your aren't using standard naming conventions (why snake case in JS/TS?) but I think I see what you're trying to do. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible. When you write `({a, b}) => a + b` without annotation you need the compiler to infer the type of `{a, b}`. If you don't give it context, it will infer `{a: any, b: any}` but then you will lose the return type. If you say it must be some supertype of `DependencyObject`, the compiler will just infer `DependencyObject`. I can't think of any way to tell the compiler to *partially* infer the type. I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: @jcalz i use snake_case out of personal preference. i just find it more readable, and i realy dont understand how camelCase became the standard for so many languages ^^
thanks for taking the time to think about it. much appreciated!

Comment: "i just find it more readable" Sure, but since you're asking for help, you might try to conform to conventions that make it easier for others to understand; specific type names should be in UpperCamelCase and values in lowerCamelCase.  Generic type parameters are usually single uppercase letters or pairs of letters, although this convention is less uniformly applied, but MACRO_CASE is not conventional for type parameters. Note that in mapped types there is a type parameter before `in` so `[key in keyof X]` is unconventional; `[K in keyof X]` is preferred. You are, of course, free to ...

Comment: ... use your own conventions, but the guidelines for [ask] are there to improve your chances of getting a good answer by making it as easy as possible for others to help.  Idiosyncratic coding styles are a hurdle for others to overcome, even if they are objectively better than the accepted convention.  Anyway, I may or may not come back to write up an answer explaining why what you're trying to do isn't working, but I wish I had at least a workaround.

Comment: I do agree with you. Next time i post a question i will stick to the Syncratic coding style. Thank you for the Advice!